# JavaScript client-side search engine

Tags: javascript

I am developing a local web application with jQuery/JavaScript.

My goal is to create search engine for searching content from a JSON file. I already made it with regex, but it works slowly.

What is the best way? Is there a JavaScript search engine?

Comment: Is it a search engine or search option?

Comment: I have html text field, when I enter a text and push "search" button, my search engine (or programme javascript, or search option) must find all occurrence in my JSON

Comment: I'm sorry, but FTW?? you're going to use _user input_ to generate a RegExp object (escaping any special chars, I hope) to process data that is _JSON_ formatted? It could be me, but since _JSON_ stands for _JavScript Object Notation_, I'm inclined to say that `RegExp` isn't the right tool for the job... in any case, you say you've already made it: show us how far you've come: post some code, or [set up a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: yes, because I haven't another solution.
the principe of algo must bee similar that Google Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it doesn't exist, you have developpe it

put your application contents in String object and developpe search function with indexOf (for target string) & substring (to extract fragment)

Answer (score 6):

Try [lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/) which supports full-text search in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The term **"search engine"** normally means that a large set of data is **indexed** (a resource intensive task). Searching the data set after indexing is then quick. If the data set is very large, it is more likely that indexing and search will be performed on the server (and only the search results are then returned to the browser).

If you just need to search fields in a JSON file that is small or medium in size, then consider JavaScript **"search algorithms"** rather than search engines.

Answer (score 2):

[Fuse.js](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse) is a lightweight fuzzy-search, in JavaScript, with zero dependencies. It has more github stars than Lunr, and has ongoing (and recent) commits as of August 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at fullproof, it's a basic search engine for use int he browser http://reyesr.github.com/fullproof/
There may be others though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options. [Lunr](https://lunrjs.com/) that is mentioned earlier and [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index).

Answer (score 0):

[Elasticlunr](http://elasticlunr.com/) is a lightweight full-text search engine in Javascript for browser search and offline search. Elasticlunr.js is developed based on [Lunr.js](https://lunrjs.com/), but more flexible than lunr.js.

Elasticlunr.js provides Query-Time boosting and field search. Elasticlunr.js is a bit like Solr, but much smaller and not as bright, but also provide flexible configuration and query-time boosting.